# PDO Memcached PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, memcached

I'm trying to implement memcached into my server due to how large the database gets so quickly. I was wondering how I'm able to implement it into this code:

```
    function getWorkers($db)
{
    $meminstance = new Memcache();
    $meminstance->pconnect('localhost', 11211);

    $del = $db->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT(address) from works');
    $del->execute();
    $arr = $del->fetchAll();
    $works = getMaxWork($db);

    foreach($arr as $a)
    {   
        $del = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM works WHERE address = \'' . $a[0] . '\'');
        $del->execute();
        $work = $del->rowCount();

        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($a[0], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $work . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . round(intval($work)/intval($works)*100, 2) . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

Comment: you do not need to query each row again, since you received already all rows in the intial sql query

Comment: Just cache the HTML you normally `echo` as a string, unless you really benefit from having the query result ready at other locations.

Comment: all you need here will be http://de2.php.net/manual/de/memcache.get.php and http://de2.php.net/manual/de/memcache.set.php but you should really think about a good caching mechanism since caching isn't a trivial thing in a application

Comment: Caching is easy... cache-invalidation, that's a hell of a thing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go

```
  function getData($db)
{
    $meminstance = new Memcache();
    $meminstance->pconnect('localhost', 11211);

    $sqlQuery = 'SELECT DISTINCT(address) from works';
    $memcacheKey = md5($sqlQuery);

    if ( $arr = $meminstance->get(memcacheKey) )
    {
        // its in cache do nothing

    }
    else
    { 
        // its not in cache, so we came here, lets now get it from db and cache it
        $del = $db->prepare($sqlQuery);
        $del->execute();
        $arr = $del->fetchAll();
        $works = getMaxWork($db);

        // lets now cache it
           $meminstance->set(memcacheKey,$arr);
      }



    foreach($arr as $a)
    {   
        $sqlQuery = 'SELECT * FROM works WHERE address = \'' . $a[0] . '\'';
         $memcacheKey = md5($sqlQuery);
         if ( $del =  $meminstance->get($memcacheKey))
           {
                 //its in cache yaaaaaaaa :D
             }
           else
           {
             $del = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM works WHERE address = \'' . $a[0] . '\'');
            $del->execute();
             $work = $del->rowCount();
             // lets cache it here
             $meminstance->set($memcacheKey,$del);

          }


        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . htmlspecialchars($a[0], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $work . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . round(intval($work)/intval($works)*100, 2) . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
}
```

The logic when you are using memcache in your website. Is it md5 the sql queries so they will be unique. You first try to fetch from memcached, ( you md5 the sql Query) so it will be the key. if you dont get anything, you get the data from database and then save it into memcache. Which means you md5 the sql Query to make they key so it will be unique, and you pass the returned result from database as its value

key ===> md5(Sql Query )
 value ==>  the object, result set that is fetched from database

// pseudocode

```
if ( Get data from memcache passed )
  {
    return result;
  }
  else
  {
    get the data from database
    save it into memcache
   }
```

Note: If you are running on a single server, better to look into APC rather than memcached

Comment: I get a PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'You cannot serialize or unserialize PDOStatement instances'